# Rails gem resque-loner NameError (uninitialized constant Resque::Plugins::UniqueJob)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed the gem, required from initializers and restarted server. But I get this error.

Gemfile
gem "resque-loner"

config/initializers/resque.rb
require 'resque-loner'

RefreshItemsJob

class RefreshItemsJob < ApplicationJob
  include Resque::Plugins::UniqueJob

Comment: That gem hasn't been updated in six years and the code in the repo doesn't inspire a lot of confidence. I'd recommend finding an alternative.

Comment: Do you know an alternative or if I can replicate with ActiveJobs?

Comment: I don't use resque so I can't recommend an alternative. I always use Sidekiq, which unlike resque is maintained and regularly updated, and includes support for a variety of unique job plugins. However, it may be impractical for you to replace your async job processor entirely.